# Как преобразовать модуль компонента в модуль формы Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Добавил компонент в проект C# (меню проекта-> добавить-> компонент). Сейчас передумал и хочу вместо него форму с тем же именем. Ситуация немного усложняется использованием системы управления версиями Visual SourceSafe. Студия создала два файла foo.cs и foo.Designer.cs
Есть способ именно преобразовать модуль компонента в форму, чтоб можно было работать с ней как будто она всегда была формой?

Comment: если под компонентом подразумевается `UserControl`, то в принципе достаточно сменить класс от которого наследуемся, т.к. и `Form`, и `UserControl` унаследованы от `ContainerControl`, поправьте если ошибаюсь. Если прав, перенесу в ответ.

Comment: @Alexey, работает, спасибо. Пометьте свой комментарий как ответ.

Comment: @rdorn, нет - имелся ввиду Component

Comment: VSS - устаревшая хрень. Переходите на SVN или GIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что мешает удалить компонент и добавить форму с тем же именем? С точки зрения СКВ файлы foo.cs и foo.Designer.cs просто будут полностью переписаны.

Comment: Вообще-то в VSS удаленный файл удаляется навсегда, ЕМНИП.

Comment: Но речь то не об этом. Собственно это то как раз и играет на руку в данной ситуации